# How to fetch results from database

Tags: php, database, wpdb

I'm attempting to customize a wordpress theme. I've added custom field cp_job with form submission. This indicates if the ad is either Buyer(Buying services) or Seller(selling services), which is now complete.

Now i want to fetch results based on buyer or seller. In this wordpress theme classipress they have ads on the side  [image]

I simply want to fetch ads which have the attribute buyer or seller, which i assume is under the mysql column cp_job. These ads will return the ad with all columns. Doing this in native PHP and mysql would be easy but working around this theme/wordpress is way more complicated as i don't understand wordpress syntax.

Any help greatly appreciated, this is urgent.  Can i have an example?

Answer (score 0):

There is likely no "cp_job" column like you are thinking. extra data/information about a wordpress post type (it looks like ads is a custom post type here) would be stored as post meta in the database.

So you might see something in the wp_post_meta table like:

meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value
XX | XX | _cp_ad_type | buyer

Once you know the name of the meta key you are looking for, you can query for this data using a [WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). Pay extra attention to the section called [Custom Field Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) which describes how to do a meta query